# Most optimised way to merge two List(s) of objects without using Comparator

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

How, do you think, can we merge two List implementations, say ArrayList(s), without having to implement the object type as Comparable, or overriding .equals() method anyways. Basically, no change to that class is allowed.
Now, the object has 4 attributes - code, name, (boolean), (float). Name cannot be used as the basis of comparison, and it is not necessary that code will always be a non-null value. Basically, either code is not null, or the boolean is set to true.
Now, if the two elements in the list are conflicting, then their (float) values need to be added up.
How can we perform this merge in most optimized way?
Its not that we can't use name as the unique identifier for each object, but issue is the names are too long which means string comparison will also be costly !

Comment: Do you have any magic pixie dust, and do you **believe**?

Comment: I have tried using hashmap - better than nested loops.

Comment: But still too many if conditions have kept the complexity so high!

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change the class to implement Comparable, you can still use external [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) objects.